# Bounty awards are unreadable

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Feast your eyes on this:

[image: Bounty Award]

'Nuff said (I hope).  Fix it, please.

Comment: that does not look appetizing... do you have a link to that example?

Comment: Sure @Jin - it's the [side dish sauce](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/4957/41) question.  I suspect that all bounties look like that though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have put in a fix for this bug. It will be in the next deployment for both the parent and meta sites.